# Looking for a script that will add in a blank row after a new value is detected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I work for a small business selling hot wheels and other diecast related products, and we are constantly needing to create lists in google sheets for pre-ordered products. I am looking for a script that will insert a blank row between every customer.

I have already automated everything to organize the data when importing a .CSV file using scripts I've found here, but manually inserting a blank row between each customer is what takes the most time. If more information is needed, just please let me know.

I found a script [here](https://www.thekeycuts.com/dear-analyst-filling-values-down-into-empty-cells-programmatically-with-google-apps-script-vba-tutorial/) that allowed me to auto fill the customers names into the empty cells below until it detects a new value. (when importing .csv, if the customer has multiple items in an order, it doesn't put their name in all cells of the customer column, only the first cell)

I'm probably wrong on this, but it seems like I might be able to adapt this script to recognize when a value is different from the one above, then add a blank row.

I am new to google sheets and scripting. So if possible, please try to explain as simply as you can. Thanks!

Edit:
Link to spreadsheet with data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W8peYL9kZhtQWdeCPP2uDkmsqy3nL1kVPmgJJq4T_80/edit#gid=2100307022

Edit:
Updated spreadsheet to show input/output examples and added more information to main post

Comment: you said "a blank row between every customer" but we can't see your sheet.  So we have no idea where the customer's are, or any details about the sheet at all.  Here's a blank sheet you can paste stuff into to help describe the problem and what you need.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W8peYL9kZhtQWdeCPP2uDkmsqy3nL1kVPmgJJq4T_80/edit

Comment: You should investigate the use of onEdit triggers.

Comment: @MattKing Pasted a small section of the current pre order list in the provided google sheets document, thank you.

Comment: @Cooper I'm not familiar with how any of that work. Do you think that what I'm asking to do will be possible using onEdit triggers? I opened app script and navigated to the triggers section and I didn't understand what any of the options meant. Again, I'm new to all this, and the information I've found on triggers is confusing to me. Thanks!

Comment: If new values are added by a user edit then onedit triggers will fire.

Comment: @Cooper I am the only one that creates and edits the sheets. I also create a new one each time as the products arrive. Once they are sent out I no longer need them.

Comment: Then you are the only one that generates onEdit triggers

Comment: Your provided sample Spreadsheet is the sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample output situation?

Comment: @Tanaike updated the sheet to provide sample input/output

Comment: @Cooper Would you be able to tell me how an onEdit Trigger might be able to help me achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

#### Insert a row into sheet when a new value appears during an edit

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  e.source.toast('Entry');//debug
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet name' && e.value) {
    sh.insertRows(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

[onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Comment: Like I mentioned in the post, I'm not really familiar with google sheets apps scripting, or code in general. So I'm not sure how to add this in to my spreadsheet to check if it works. I also am not sure if this will work because I am looking for it to read information from a specific column (Customer column) and I'm not seeing any kind of Range defined in the code. Sorry if I'm being difficult, just new to all this.

Comment: Just load it into your script editor; edit the sheet name; and then edit the sheet and change a value